# Unable to generate access token for Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-authentication

My ask is to generate a token for Power Bi so to achieve it I created an application for organization by selecting **Embedded for your organization**
So, to integrate with Azure AD created the application in Azure AD.

The endpoint I used is    `POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`

and in the body tab, I gave the below inputs:

```
data: {
    grant_type: password
    scope:
    resource:
    client_id:
    username:
    password:
    }
```

My requirement is to generate token with ROPC authentication flow only.

This is the page I am referring to [Solved: Re: How to generate the authorization code and the... - Microsoft Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-generate-the-authorization-code-and-the-access-token-to/m-p/409409#M12204)

But after hitting send got this error:

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: \r\nCorrelation ID: \r\nTimestamp: 2022-09-25 13:40:05Z",
]
```

Not sure what am I missing in configuring the application or postman. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why ROPC?  You should be using the client credentials flow using your app registration's client id and client secret. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```json
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
data: {
    grant_type: password
    scope: openid
    resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
    client_id: ******
    username: ******
    password: ******
    }
```

[image]

If your application is not public, then add **`client_secret`** parameter like below:

To resolve the error, add the parameters in ***Body tab*** -> **`x-www-form-urlencoded`**

**I am able to generate the access token successfully like below:**

[image]
[image]