# PowerBI Secure Access Blob Storage

Tags: security, powerbi, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I have created a PowerBI report with embedded videos using the HTML customer visual. The videos are hosted on an Azure Blob Storage so I have generated a SAS token that I have added to the video URL in my data.

However, I would look to increase the security of Blob Storage and find a better solution to avoid having a SAS token out there for everyone to use and with limited control over.

For example, would it be possible to access a token provider that would generate an access token on the fly if a set of credentials is correct? This way,  I would be able to control the access to the videos.

I looked into Shared Access Signature but was not able to implement it from PowerBi. Any other ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To avoid a SAS token accessible to everyone, try generating the access token by specifying user's IP address or IP Range who are allowed to access:

[image]

If the user's IP address is not in the range, **the user will get the below error while accessing the SAS URL**:

[image]

> Would it be possible to access a token provider that would generate an access token on the fly if a set of credentials is correct.

You can make use of **Authorization-Code Flow** to generate the access token which will ask for the Users interaction while generating the token.

Make use of the below **Parameters** to generate the access token:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

 

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:*****
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:scope
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code:code
```

A sign-in screen will appear to validate the Users credentials:

[image]

Access token got generated successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the Authorization-Code Flow looks like what I am looking for: I have been looking into it, but I was wondering where/how you are implementing the Parameters code to generate the Access token in PowerBI ? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Kindly check this  [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73878155/unable-to-generate-access-token-for-powerbi) & [ref2](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-generate-the-authorization-code-and-the-access-token-to/m-p/408248)